# CSS Behaviour for IE: first-of-type

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, behavior

I wanted to use a CSS behaviour to target the first `p` element in a `div`, which is not the first element in the `div`.

I saw a similar question on here which answered with using cascading selectors to the p in the div, like:

```
div h1 p
```

As I may not know what the first element may be (maybe `h1` or `h2` etc, I was wondering whether it was possible to mimic the `:first-of-type` using IEs behaviours in CSS.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well, jQuery can do it, and that means that JavaScript can do it as well. CSS alone cannot (obviously as IE doesn't support it).

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: Those users should get with the times and upgrade. Replacing CSS behaviors with jQuery is not a solution to cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: @animuson: If it would be that easy, the world would be a great place...

Comment: @animuson When something is not possible with CSS, JavaScript is usually the only way to go...

Answer (score -1):

This works fine

```
div p:first-of-type {
    background:red;
}
```

for this

```
<div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something else</p>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zJaAa/1/

Comment: What browser did you test this on? IE<9 will not support it.

Comment: Only Chrome.  For non-modern browsers, I'm  pretty sure only js will do it.

Comment: I actually stated this was for IE, should have been more specific meaning IE6-8 for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Actually, apologies... I forgot to mention the IE requirement. Sorry!

Comment: @Designermonkey no you didn't you put it in the title and the tags, that's more then enough.